# Charset and UTF-8 in a downloaded text file on a Mac

Tags: php, macos, utf-8, character-encoding

We have a PHP/MYSQL application that collects user input, including special characters like ø,ü,ñ, etc  Database is capturing them, and they can be seen via PHPmyAdmin. Download on windows is fine.  Display on a mac browser is fine.

When users download the text file on a Mac OSX, the unicode characters come out as other characters.  If I save the PHP file as with UTF-8 with BOM, (which apparently affects PHP output) they come out as little black diamonds.

Here is the output header I am using

mb_http_output("UTF-8");
header('Content-type: application/xml; charset="utf-8"');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.xml");
die($text);

Any tips greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm using textwrangler on the mac, which I thought to be reputable.

Apikot's answer did help in one specific case where the ø character came across as another single char.  Thanks Apikot!

there may be two things happening 
@Cal  Here is an example like you describe, BÃ¼lowstr. 30, KÃ¶ln
But this shows up in the phpMyAdmin as well I think the MYSQL collation should be utf-8.  

Thank you both!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you tried:

```
$text = utf8_encode($text);
die($text);
```

?

Comment: i suspect this does not do what you think it does. utf8_encode() turns a Latin-1/ISO-8859-1 string into UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

There could be several things wrong, but it sounds like the editor you're opening the file up in on your mac is not recognizing the file as UTF-8, even though it is. Do accented characters appear as two characters each, the first of which is a capital A? That means you're looking at UTF-8 bytes, treated as if they were Latin-1.

It would be easier to know for sure if you could upload the resulting file somewhere :)